# Derivative of definite integrals with interval variables inside the integral i.e.: $ \frac{d}{dx} \int_a^x{(x-t)^n f^{(n+1)}(t)}dt $

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

How do I differentiate definite integrals with the variable of differentiation as the upper or lower limit of integration / inside the integral such as the one below?
$$ \frac{d}{dx} \int_a^x{(x-t)^n f^{(n+1)}(t)}dt $$
I know that integrating regular integrals i.e.: $ \frac{d}{dx} \int_a^x{f(t)}dt =f(x) $ 
Here, $x$ is the upper bound but $x$ is also within $ (x-t)^n $ so what happens to that?
$$ $$
Edit: is it possible to have a general solution to this? Fundamental theorem of calculus says $ \frac{d}{dx} \int_a^x{f(t)}dt =f(x) $ but what about $ \frac{d}{dx} \int_a^x{f(t, x)}dt $ ?
$$ $$
Edit2: obviously
$$ \frac{d}{dx} \int_0^x {(x + t)^2}dt = \frac{d}{dx} \left(\frac{(x+t)^3}{3}\big|^x_0\right) = \frac{d}{dx}\frac{7x^3}{3} = 7x^2$$
but
$$ \frac{d}{dx} \int_0^x {(x + t)^2}dt \not= (x+t)^2\big|^x_0 = 3x^2$$

Comment: You should have the answer $$\Gamma(n+1)(f'(x) + p_{n-1} ( x-a). $$ where $p_{n-1} $ is a polynomial of degree $n-1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use integration by parts $n$ times. I'll get you started: let $u=(x-t)^n$ and $dv=f^{(n+1)}(t)\,dt$. Then $du=-n(x-t)^{n-1}$ and $v=f^{(n)}(t)$. Thus, $$\frac{d}{dx}\int_0^x(x-t)^nf^{(n+1)}(t)\,dt=\frac{d}{dx}\left((x-t)^nf^{(n)}(t)\big|^x_a+n\int_0^x (x-t)^{n-1}f^{(n)}(t)\,dt\right)$$
$$=-n(x-a)^{n-1}f^{(n)}(a)+n\frac{d}{dx}\int_0^x (x-t)^{n-1}f^{(n)}(t)\,dt$$

now do this $n-1$ more times (Hint: induction is your friend.)

Comment: Is that correct? Using the identity $ \int {u}dv = uv - \int {v}du $ means that $ \int {(x-t)^nf^{(n+1)}(t)}dt = f^{(n)}(t)(x-t)^n+n\int {(x-t)^{n-1}f^{(n)}(t)dt} $ which is different from what you have.

Comment: Thanks for the correction, I fixed it.