# Differentiating definite integrals with variable limits in the form $\int_0^x f(x)f(t)dt$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration

I am aware of a question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1728242/derivative-of-definite-integrals-with-interval-variables-inside-the-integral-i-e?newreg=98657e5c49904196b8a8a7cadc542030) that has similar intent, but the integral in question has a particular form such that the accepted answer does not work in general, for example $\int_0^x e^xf(t)dt$.

When the integrand is independent of the limit, $$\frac{d}{dx}\int_0^x f(t)dt=f(x)$$
I would like to know how in general I can evaluate,
$$\frac{d}{dx} \int^x_0 f(x)f(t)dt$$
Or if $f(x)$ is too general to say anything, how can I deal with derivatives that do not vanish with integration by parts such as $f(x)=e^x,\frac{1}{x}, ..$

Comment: This is [Leibniz's rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule).

Comment: $f(x)$ goes out of the integral

Answer (score 5):

In general, if you have $F(x) = \int_0^x g(x) f(t)\, dt$, where $g$ is a differentiable function, and $f$ is continuous, then you can calculate $F'(x)$ using the product rule and the Fundamental theorem of calculus:
\begin{align}
F(x) &= \int_0^x g(x)f(t)\, dt = g(x) \cdot\int_0^xf(t)\, dt
\end{align}
So,
\begin{align}
F'(x) &= g'(x)\int_0^x f(t)\, dt + g(x)f(x).
\end{align}

---

Note that similar reasoning holds if you want to differentiate a function like $H(x) = \int_{\alpha(x)}^{\beta(x)} g(x) f(t)\, dt$ (where $f$ is continuous, and $\alpha,\beta,g$ are differentiable).